# How can I display Category tiles in "My Courses" page (ie. courses.php) instead of list of courses?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme, moodle-boost

I am using Moodle 4.0.4 and boost theme, I want Categories to be displayed as tiles in "My Courses" page (i.e., courses.php page), where the users click the category first then see all the courses in that category.

I found a block plugin named Category Tiles Block:
https://github.com/frumbert/moodle-block_category_tiles/tree/master

I was able to install it but the problem is instead of My Courses page, I am able to use the category tiles blocks only in the Dashboard (screenshot attached).

How can I add edit the My Courses page to include this block and hide the course list?
Or is there any other plugin that suits my need better than this plugin?
Please help!

Thanks in advance [image]

I installed a plugin expecting it to show course categories as tiles in the my courses page. But it displays the categories of tiles only in the dashboard page.